# javascript how can I remove a parent div from onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the parent when the button is clicked.

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="" alt="First">
  <button id="one" class="remove" onclick="removeThis('one');">X</button>
</div>

<script>
function removeThis(_this){
alert("hello" + _this);
    $(_this).parents.remove();
};
</script>
```

This is't working

entire code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function registerClickHandler () {
  // Implement the click handler here for button of class 'remove'

}

function removeThis(_this){
alert("hello" + _this);
   // $('#' + _this).parents().remove();
    _this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild( _this.parentNode );
};

</script>


<div class="image">
  <img src="" alt="First">
  <button id="one" class="remove" onclick="removeThis('one');">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="" alt="Second">
  <button id="second" class="remove" onclick="registerClickHandler()">X</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$()` is a `jQuery` selector and to use it you must include the `jQuery` library... If you notice something isn't functioning as intended while working with javascript be sure to open the browser console as that will display error  messages (if any) and tell you which line the error is on so the browser console is very helpful, please use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were not invoking `parents()` method

replace

```
$(_this).parents.remove();
```

with

```
$(_this).parents().remove();
```

or in your case

```
$(_this).parent().remove();
```

Since you have not included `jquery` tag in your question, you can use the following vanilla js as well

```
_this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild( _this.parentNode );
```

You also need to pass this reference to this method call as well

```
<button id="one" class="remove" onclick="removeThis(this);">X</button>
```

Based on your updated code, try changing the method to this

```
function removeThis(_this){
   var el = document.getElementById( _this.id ); //assuming '_this' is the 'this' reference not the 'id'
   el.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild( el.parentNode );
};
```

Comment: tried this, thanks for the reply but its still not working

Comment: Have you included jquery in the html page?

Comment: Updated with vanilla js as well. Which w3school example? please share the link.

Comment: iv changed the data in the link ...il update my Q with the entire code

Comment: Anyways, you try the vanilla js code I have suggested as well.

Comment: @John You didn't included jquery, however, I have suggested the changes you can try.

Comment: @gurvinder372 shouldn't your selector target the `id` like `document.getElementById(_this.id)` if you plan to use `getElementById()`?

Comment: @NewToJS in its original code OP was passing the id as is `<button id="one" class="remove" onclick="removeThis('one');">X</button>`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes, I can see that but in your answer you pass `this` which the OP will use/test your changes. I understand what you mean but mixing methods up can be misleading. Maybe make it more clear when offering multiple methods for example **Method1:** and split them up using a horizontal rule. Just a suggestion to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this if you are using jQuery:

from

```
$(_this).parents.remove();
```

to

```
$("#" + _this).parents().remove();
```

If you are using vanilla JS then change to the following:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="" alt="First">
    <button id="one" class="remove" onclick="removeThis(this);">X</button>
</div>

function removeThis(ele) {
    ele.parentNode.remove();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have use `#` for using id selector of `button` so its working fine

```js
function removeThis(_this) {
  alert("hello" + _this);
  $('#' + _this).parent().remove();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
  <img src="" alt="First">
  <button id="one" class="remove" onclick="removeThis('one');">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that resolved it with Jquery but for this instance it has to be JS

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="image" ID="DivParent">
  <img src="" alt="First">
  <button id="one" class="remove" onclick="removeThis();">X</button>
</div>
<script>
function removeThis(this){
    $("#DivParent").hide();
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in your code

1. Replace `parents` with `parents()`. Refer [JQuery DOM](https://api.jquery.com/?s=DOM)
2. If you're loading Jquery anyway, then make full use of it (e.g. [click event](https://api.jquery.com/click/))

   ```
   <div class="image">
       <img src="" alt="First">
       <button id="one" class="remove">X</button>
   </div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#one").click(function() {
               alert("Test");
               $("#one").parent().remove();
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

If you only want to remove only the previous immediate element, it can be done by using [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Like this => `$("#one").prev().remove();`

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a420mukh/)**